# How mock User.Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, mocking, moq

I want to testing one method in controller

```
public class CardController : Controller
    {
        IRepository repository;
        public CardController(IRepository repo)
        {
            repository = repo;
        }
        [AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
        public IActionResult CheckPublicID(string PublicID)
        {
            if (repository.CheckCardName(PublicID, User.Identity.Name))
            {
                return Json(true);
            }
            return Json(false);
        }
```

How i can add mock User.Identity.Name in HttpContext to my mock controller?

```
[Fact]
        public void CheckPublicIDIsEmpty()
        {

            Mock<IRepository> mock = new Mock<IRepository>();
            mock.Setup(r => r.CheckCardName("TestID", "TestName")).Returns(false);
            //mock User.Identity.Name
            CardController cardController = new CardController(mock.Object);
            
            var result = cardController.CheckPublicID("TestID");

            var viewResult = Assert.IsType<JsonResult>(result);
            Assert.Equal(false, viewResult.Value);
        }
```

*change Assert

Comment: User property actually refers to HttpContext - `public ClaimsPrincipal User => HttpContext?.User;` so you need to mock HttpContext instead. See this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38561138/1752270). Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mock the `HttpContext` on the controller for example :

```cs
var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext()
{
   User = new System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal(new GenericIdentity("username"))
};
var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteData(), 
                                                   new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionDescriptor());
cardController.ControllerContext = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerContext(actionContext);
```